# Magento - edit multiple original tables of magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I want to edit some tables of magento and I've made a module to do that.
For example I want to edit table "catalog_product_bundle_price_index".

Here is the global section of my config.xml :

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
        <mymodule_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_read>
        <mymodule_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_write>
    </resources>
</global>
```

And here is the code in mysql4-install-1.0.0.php :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$tables = array(
        $installer->getTable('bundle/price_index') => array(
                'columns' => array(
                        'min_price' => array(
                                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                                'scale'     => 4,
                                'precision' => 16,
                                'nullable'  => false,
                                'comment'   => 'Min Price'
                        ),
                        'max_price' => array(
                                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                                'scale'     => 4,
                                'precision' => 16,
                                'nullable'  => false,
                                'comment'   => 'Max Price'
                        )
                ),
                'comment' => 'Catalog Product Bundle Price Index'
        )
);



$installer->getConnection()->modifyTables($tables);
$installer->endSetup();
```

but it does not work, What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE :**

I make this module to change 'min_price' and 'max_price' from decimal(12,4) to decimal(16,4); but it is not changed!

Comment: Magento has its own Stackexchange site - [magento.se]. You'll probably do better asking there.

Comment: actually I asked there, but no one answered. I thought that more people would see my question here. thanks for your suggestion anyway :)

Comment: Please define "does not work" more precisely. What do you expect to happen and what actually happens instead? Is your script started for sure? Does the `core_resource` table contain an entry for your module? Do you get any errors? If so, which errors do you get?